# Can I merge an old account into a new one?

Tags: support, login, user-accounts, merge-accounts

I just remembered that I made an old account 2 years and 5 months ago. For some reason, I stopped using that login, and now I have my main account (the one I'm using to post this question). I went through the ["merging" process](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts), and after confirming that I own both accounts, I came to a page stating:

> Thank you for confirming ownership of your accounts. The account DJ McMayhem will be removed, and all rep and votes will be transferred to account user2874724 as a result of this merge. Please click OK to confirm.

I don't want to delete DJMcMayhem! That's the one I have been active on, with my correct email and settings and contributions and network profiles! Is there anyway I can merge the old one into my new one?

Comment: Did you try [Contact Us](http://meta.stackexchange.com/contact)?